# Change directory and branch within CVS repository to read-only

Tags: svn, migration, cvs

We are moving to SVN and need to prevent commits to specific directories/modules within the CVS repository. What is the best way of doing this?

I have currently set the filesystem permissions for this directory to read-only and seems to do the job for now - but is there a 'cvs' way of doing this?

Also, can I make a specific branch read-only?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this by creating a pre-commit hook to disallow checkins on the branch, eg see [here](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/LettingCVSPullTheTrigger.rdoc)

[edited following Ray's comment]

Comment: You'd want a pre-commit hook to prevent adding changes to a branch.  A post-commit hook is how to trigger something afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cvs_acls, which comes with the CVS distribution. It allows you to define branch-level permissions for commits.